# How to open a webview activity from a button

Tags: java, android, webview

I am making an app which contains 2 buttons and when the user will click either of the 2 buttons I would like them to be redirected to a web page. I have made the XML code of the buttons and the webview activity. I have also made the webview activity java file. My question now is how do I set it so that when the user clicks a button the app will start the webview activity?

Also, how do I set the webview activity java to open a link or the other from another button?

These are my button XML code

```
 <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:src="@drawable/uninstall"
    android:text="@string/uninstall_img"
    android:autoLink="all"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/donate"
    android:src="@drawable/donate"
    android:text="@string/about_link"
    android:autoLink="all"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

This is my webview activity java code

```
  public class webviewacivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://goo.gl/dUT1Ob");

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    }
}
```

NOTE

I didn't add the button activity in my activitymain.java because it always shows errors. I'll be happy if you show me that code also.

I am not very good at java and I know it just a little bit so I will just copy and paste the code. :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use your buttons in your main activity, you need to add click listeners to your buttons. Then you can use the button clicks to create an Intent to start you webview activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.donate);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainAcitivity.this, WebViewActivity.class));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Basic in your activitymain:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   findViewById(R.id.imageButton).setOnClickListener(getOnClickListener());
   findViewById(R.id.donate).setOnClickListener(getOnClickListener());

}
private View.OnClickListener getOnClickListener() {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(activitymain.this, webviewacivity.class));
        }
    };
}
```